# How do I execute maven plugin for parent module only?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

So I created this small maven plugin, that would connect to the database server and create all the tables I need for the project. Thing is, that the project consists of multiple modules and I want the plugin to be defined in the parent one. Yet it needs to be executed only once, not separately for each module. I thought that adding `"<inherited>false</inherited>"` to the plugin configuration would be enough, but apparently it's not.
Here's the pom of my parent project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>rpg</groupId>
    <artifactId>rpg-build</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>rpg-build</name>

    <modules>
        <module>../rpg-web</module>
    <module>../rpg-service</module>
    <module>../rpg-commons</module>
    <module>../rpg-maven-plugin</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>rpg.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>rpg-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You should add `@aggregator` annotation to your plugin's mojo.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:

> You should add @aggregator annotation to your plugin's mojo. –  Andrew
>   Logvinov Apr 1 '13 at 12:40